# Conditional aggregation using when()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing an aggregation like this:

```
df2 = (
    df1
    .groupby('date', 'id', 'product')
    .agg(
        sf.count('new_user').alias('new_users'),
        sf.count('eligible_user').alias('eligible_users')
    
    )
)
```

I would like to count `new_user` where `eligible_user` is null. I have tried doing it like so:

```
df2 = (
    df1
    .groupby('date', 'id', 'product')
    .agg(
        sf.when(sf.col('eligible_user').isNull(), sf.count('new_user').alias('new_users')),
        sf.count('eligible_user').alias('eligible_users')       
    )
)
```

This errors out:

> Cannot resolve `eligible_user` given input columns.

I'm not sure why I get this error since `eligible_user` is in `df1` (first query works). I cannot simply put a `.where()` for this condition prior to the `groupby()`, as I want to include rows with `eligible_user == 1` in the `eligible_users` count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a conditional count, you can use

```
sf.count(sf.when(sf.col('eligible_user').isNull(), sf.col('new_user')))
```

The count should be outside the `when`, not inside.